# Set opacity for marks but not in legend

Tags: altair, vega-lite

I can modify the classic [Simple Scatter Plot with Tooltips](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_tooltips.html), to add opacity to marks, but I'd like to legend colors to stay 100% opaque. In the chart I'm trying to make, I have a df with tens of thousands of rows.

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60, opacity=0.1).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin'
)
```

[image: chart result]

I've tried [`alt.Legend`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Legend.html)'s `symbolOpacity` and `gradientOpacity` to no avail

```py
color=alt.Color(
    'Origin:N',
    legend=alt.Legend(
        # symbolOpacity=1,
        gradientOpacity=1,
)
)
```

Comment: I believe `symbolOpacity` should be the way to do this. The fact that it has no effect is probably a vega-lite bug, and should be reported there. Here's a minimal reproduction of the issue in vega-lite: [vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA28QAspQA4Gc4B6IgNwFMBzCAOkoEspNEAjG+gezKogFpIY+clHxEBEIgGMIyfDQBW+DgDsQAXwA0IALYyA1vFBQAnrnIZJ9ZJNTmtHXBEsn4ABhoBGTSHLLJHMHplSkMQf1QOZFCAM3pyVDAMAHlkegZVLRMzDGUObSCIdC1bSl9EhBB8Y20WDlQkx2djeC9vAA8YuISMAAlIoVwOAHdyKMzTczgQAEdECGUoRmh6CnUtZorY+PKQAFl6W3wAfTNkI4BxQoiMkCzJmbmFpcXVtTegA).

Comment: always happy to learn that its not a "me" problem. thanks @jvp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, this seems to be a bug with `vega-lite`. Per @jvp's suggestion, I've filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/6719)

UPDATE -- IT'S FIXED